# How do I what Content Types are on offer (for HTTP Content Negotiation)?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-type, content-negotiation, doi

What one gets back when resolving a DOI depends on content negotiation.
I was looking at https://citation.crosscite.org/docs.html#sec-3
and I see different services offer different Content Types.

For a particular URL I want to know **all** the content types it can give me.
Some of them might be more useful than any that I am aware of (i.e. i don't want to write a list of preferences in advance).

For example:

https://doi.org/10.5061/dryad.1r170

I thought maybe OPTIONS was the way to do it

but that gave back nothing interesting, only about allowed request methods.

```
shell> curl  -v -X OPTIONS   http://doi.org/10.5061/dryad.1r170
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 2600:1f14:6cf:c01::d...
*   Trying 54.191.229.235...
* Connected to doi.org (2600:1f14:6cf:c01::d) port 80 (#0)
> OPTIONS /10.5061/dryad.1r170 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: doi.org
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 07:01:14 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host doi.org left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no such standard yet, but Link header: https://www.w3.org/wiki/LinkHeader could expose this information.

But personally, I won't rely too much on it. For example, a server could start sending a new content type and still NOT expose it via this header.

It might be useful to check the API response headers frequently, via manual or automated means for any changes.